# Twitter Bootstrap timepicker defaultTime NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

I have read that you can set a preset time with the defaultTime parameter, however all this is giving me is NaN in the value spinner for hours/minutes when you try to use it.

Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('.datepicker').datepicker() ;
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
    minuteStep: 5,
    showInputs: false,
    disableFocus: true,
    showMeridian: false,
    defaultTime: '00:00'
});
})
```

PS I want it to be 00:00 because I am using it as a "duration" picker, not time.

How do I fix this?

---

Timepicker: http://jdewit.github.com/bootstrap-timepicker/

Datepicker: http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Comment: There is a datepicker in twitter bootstrap? Can you link the doc

Comment: @Jonathan de M. See edit.

Comment: use defaultTime: false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use value instead:

```
$('.timepicker').timepicker({
    minuteStep: 5,
    showInputs: false,
    disableFocus: true,
    showMeridian: false,
    defaultTime: 'value'
});
```

It then uses the value from the input field as a start point instead of the current time, here's the HTML:

```
<div>
    <input class="timepicker" type="text" class="input-small" value="00:00">
    <i class="icon-time"></i>
</div>
```

I tried the answer above and it didn't work for me!

Answer (score 1):

I'm the author of the **jdewit/bootstrap-timepicker**.
It recently got some updates and the **'value'** option has been deprecated.

Your initial attempt now works.

```js
  $('.timepicker').timepicker({
        defaultTime: '00:00'
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following format

```
defaultTime:'00:00:00'
```

edit:

> Set the initial time value. Setting it to 'current' sets it to the
>   current time. Options available [current, value, or an actual time
>   e.g. 01:00]